# Qt program seg faults when I try to insert a pair into a map

Tags: c++, dictionary, qt4, segmentation-fault

I am working on my first Qt application, widget really, and I am getting a segfault when I try to fill up a standard library map with a `<int, QString>` pair. My goal is to fill the map with int keys and QString values. I don't know if pair is the best way to do this, so any advice would be great.

Here is the only source file besides the main.

```
#include "linuxtips.h"
#include "ui_linuxtips.h"

LinuxTips::LinuxTips(QWidget *parent) :
  QWidget(parent),
  ui(new Ui::LinuxTips)
{
  loadRandTip();
  ui->setupUi(this);
}

LinuxTips::~LinuxTips()
{
  delete ui;
}

void LinuxTips::on_learnMore_clicked()
{

}

void LinuxTips::on_viewAll_clicked()
{

}

void LinuxTips::loadRandTip()
{
  int i = 0;
  std::map<int, QString>::iterator it;

  QString line;
  QFile inputFile(":/tipFile.txt");
  inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

  QTextStream in(&inputFile);
  do{
    line = in.readLine();
  //  this->TipMap.insert(it, std::pair<int, QString >(i,line));
    i++;
  }while(!in.atEnd());
}
```

If I uncomment `this->TipMap.insert(it, std::pair<int, QString >(i,line));` then it will run. Since it's a seg fault I'm sure its a memory overflow or null pointer, but I'm just not sure what it is. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you look at the stack trace?

Comment: When I tried to put multiple breakpoints in the main function and before the commented lines. The program crashes immediately and never stops at any of the break points. Same when I used Valgrind. There was no output, just a crash notification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your crash is due to these lines:

```
std::map<int, QString>::iterator it;
this->TipMap.insert(it, std::pair<int, QString >(i,line));
```

You're attempting to insert into a map using an invalid (uninitialized) iterator. Are you running this in debug or release? You should get an assertion in debug.

Comment: I try to run it in debug, but it crashes and doesn't stop at any breakpoints. It sprays disassembler output all across the screen, but that doesn't seem too helpful. Or is it?

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. Initialized it with `it(this->TipMap.begin())`

Comment: @CallMeNorm: The question is, why are you using the `insert` version that expects a hint iterator? If you always pass `begin()`, there is no point, you should simply pass the pair.

Comment: Or just use the **[]** operator.

Comment: Thanks for the additional feedback, now that its working I can finetune a bit.